# Attaching a screen to a name

Tags: gnu-screen

Okay for me to load a screen I have to do screen -r server

Is there a way I can set it up so that  can just be shown by the command: screen -x name

Comment: Do you have more than 2 detached screen sessions? If you have 1 and use `screen -x` it reconnects to it for me.

Comment: I do, but I know what server it is when I do server -ls

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on what it is you're actually trying to accomplish? Your question is very vague at this point.

Comment: Okay when I do screen -r it says something like this:

server (detached) <-- this one I want to have do screen -x name
server2 (attached)

Right now the only way for me to vie the screen is to do screen -r server. I want to do screen -x name

Comment: Please update the Q, I do not understand what you're saying in the comments either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `screen -S name`?

Comment: Then will it allow me to do screen -x name to connect to the screen?

Comment: Yes it will allow you to connect to the screen.

Comment: I have 2 servers on the -ls, how do I connect one to the screen -S name